# Firefox urlbar rewrite: http://server/ → http://www.server.com/?

Tags: firefox, url-rewriting, autocomplete, address-bar

Since Firefox 83, addresses typed in the urlbar are rewritten:
**http://server/** → **http://www.server.com/**

I've tried to disable the browser.urlbar.trimURLs option in `about:config`, but nothing changes.